# Default Elevation of Card, Table in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to look for the default elevation provided by Mui on Card and Table on their documentation if you don't explicitly write `elevation={3}` on the component.
What is the default elevation for them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the [API page of MUI Card component](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/card/#props) it states that:

*"Props of the [Paper](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/paper/) component are also available."*

And on the [API page of MUI Paper component](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/paper/#props) it shows that the default value for the `elevation` prop is `1`.

[image]